# Цвета спрайтов в фотошопе насыщеннее, чем в юнити

Tags: unity3d

столкнулся с такой проблемой при импорте спрайтов в юнити: цвета спрайтов в фотошопе насыщеннее, чем цвета этих же спрайтов в юнити. Искал ответ на разных форумах, но к сожалению ничего не нашел. Вся надежда на вас)

Вот ссылка на изображения: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XKDF.jpg

Comment: попробуйте не 960х320, а 1024х1024 и другой формат кратный 2 (но лучше не больше 2048) в любом редакторе можно поменять(хоть в пэинте)

Comment: на устройстве (если для мобилок) еще хуже будет выглядеть)

Comment: Какой `Color space` стоит в проекте?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, где этот Color space можно посмотреть? Я в юнити новичек и еще не очень много знаю.

Comment: В project settings, погуглите, мне неудобно с телефона весь процесс поиска описывать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, если я в правильном месте нашел, то у меня там стоит Gamma (это в окне project settings в разделе Player)

Comment: @Ilya поставьте альфу вместо гаммы, это влияет на общую яркость при отрисовке, подозреваю, что и на 2д спрайты это влияет.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker там нету alpha, там есть только Gamma, которая стоит сейчас и Linear. Может я не в том месте нашел?

Comment: @Ilya не не, все верно, линейную ставьте. Это меня не туда повело. Гамма получше, но в 2д разницы от этой пользы нет, но в целом яркость цветов должна увеличиться.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker не помогло. Я даже перезапускал юнити и заново заливал спрайты, цвета такие же.

Comment: Тогда надо думать над своим шейдером или смотреть на весь процесс создания этих спрайтов, в принципе это окно импорта не отражает то, как оно в игре будет выглядеть.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ладно, буду думать, спасибо что пытались мне помочь. Я даже пробовал сделать как посоветовал Anton Nikolaev, создал в фотошопе файл размером 1024x1024 и перенес туда слои с графикой, но и это не помогло, не знаю может я тоже что-то не так сделал.

Comment: @Ilya я бы на вашем месте попытался посмотреть конечный вид в игре.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я расставил разные объекте по сцене и скомпилировал игру, затем запустил ее и ничего не поменялось, цвета как были тусклыми, так и остались.

Comment: @AntonNikolaev, вы имеете ввиду разрешение атласа? Если да, то я сделал файл размером 1024x1024 и перенес туда слой с графикой и затем залил в юнити - это не помогло.

Comment: А вообще еще можно попробовать отключить компрессию.

Comment: #RiotBr3aker как эту компрессию отключить?

Comment: @Ilya в настройках импорта атласа, в самом низу есть 4 строки, одна из них Compression - поставьте там None.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker там всего 3 строки, четвертой нету. В ответах, которые мне дали посмотри скриншот.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это метод. Она улучшает графику но по поводу цветов не уверен.
Для каждого спрайта -
Format должен быть на RGBA 32bit.
А Max Size должен быть на самом высоком размере.

[image]

Comment: #Eccs0103, я так всегда и выставляю, RGBA 32 bit делает спрайты нормальными, потому, что очень часто они искажаются после того, как в Filter Mode выбрать Point(No Filter), на цвета это не влияет, но все равно спасибо, что пытаетесь мне помочь.